# Determine the width of a ggplot2 plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use gridExtra to combine two ggplot2 bar plots (with coordinates flipped so that the labels take up horizontal space). The problem is that some of the labels are short and some are long. I want the width of the left and right columns to be the same, irrespective of the width of the labels. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

datashort <- data.frame(ecks = c("Short1", "Short2", "Short3"), why = c(30, 20, 40))
datalong <- data.frame(ecks = c(paste0("Really, Really, Really, Really Long", c(1:3))), 
                       why = c(20, 30, 40))

plotshort <- ggplot(data = datashort, aes(x = ecks, y = why, width = .5)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), limits = c(0, 50)) +
  coord_flip()

plotlong <- ggplot(data = datalong, aes(x = ecks, y = why, width = .5)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), limits = c(0, 50)) +
  coord_flip()

grid.arrange(plotshort, plotlong, ncol = 2)
```

If you do that, you get a really wide left chart and a really squished right chart. I know that you can add widths to the grid arrange, but I'd like to know exactly what they should be. Here it looks like widths=c(.4, .6) works pretty well, but it's not exact. Also, you have to use trial and error to get there, which isn't ideal. Is there any way to figure out what the actual plot area is so that you can calculate the right widths?

Comment: you can use `egg::ggarrange`

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181051/r-ggplot2-size-of-plot-area. Also, may help if you break the labels in many lines before generating the plot: `datalong$ecks <- gsub(' ', '\n', datalong$ecks)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very simple solution would be to use `cowplot`:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotshort, plotlong, ncol = 2,align = "v")
```

[image]

The argument `align` allows you to set the plot areas equal.

Or another option would be to add some breaks to the titles:

```
library(stringr)

plotlong <- datalong %>%
    mutate(ecks = str_replace_all(ecks, "[[:punct:]]\\s|\\s", "\\\n")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = ecks, y = why, width = .5)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), limits = c(0, 50)) +
    coord_flip()

cowplot::plot_grid(plotshort, plotlong, ncol = 2,align = "v")
```

[image]

If you add the breaks, then you could use `grid.arrange`

```
grid.arrange(plotshort, plotlong, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going with the cowplot solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the labels using `stringr` and modify your `ggplot2` script to define your labels in `st_wrap` and plot as `scale_x_discrete`:

```
library(stringr)    

plotshort <- ggplot(data = datashort, aes(x = ecks, y = why, width = .5)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = str_wrap(c("Short1", "Short2", "Short3"), width = 10))  

plotlong <- ggplot(data = datalong, aes(x = ecks, y = why, width = .5)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = str_wrap(c("Really, Really, Really, Really Long1", "Really, Really, Really, Really Long2", "Really, Really, Really, Really Long3"), width = 10))  

grid.arrange(plotshort, plotlong, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This works just fine with this data, but the actual data I'm working with has ~70 rows, so it's not really convenient to wrap them. Also, that still doesn't make the plot area equal size, it just avoids some squishing.